# Example on Transportaion dilemma

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

A lumber company ships pine flooring from its three mills, A 1 ,
A 2 and A 3 , to three building suppliers, B 1 , B 2 and B 3 . The
table below shows the demand, availabilities and unit costs of
transportation. Starting with the north-west corner solution
and using the stepping-stone method, determine the
transportation pattern that minimises the total cost.
[image]

The distribution matrix with nothes-west corner method give the following matrix : 
{ [25,0,0] , [5,30,5] , [0,0,31] } 
then i compute the improvements indices for unused cells , and check for optimal. it's not optimal sol cell (3,1) is negative 1 .
I cannot apply stepping stone method on this distribution matrix because the second row has three consecutive basic cell . What is the optimal solution ?

Comment: No , i found it in Lecture paper  [page 19 ](http://cms.lmu.edu.ng/pluginfile.php/9802/mod_resource/content/1/LECTURES%208%20%209%20TRANSPORTATION%20PROBLEMS.pdf)

 it's an exercise

Answer (score 0):

The Optimal distribution Matrix is { [0,0,25],[0,30,10],[30,0,1] }.
The Optimal cost = 25*(2)+30*(2)+10*(3)+30*(3)+1*(3) = 233
the answer obtained after three iterations.